# What's the difference between returning void and {.noreturn.}?

Tags: pragma, nim-lang

In Nim, the [noReturn pragma](http://devdocs.io/nim/manual#pragmas-noreturn-pragma) marks a proc that never returns.

How is that different than a function that returns `void`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Returning `void` means the function returns nothing:

```
proc saySomething(): void =
  echo "something"
```

The empty brackets as well as the `: void` are optional:

```
proc saySomething =
  echo "something"
```

Annotating a function with `noReturn` means the function will not return at all:

```
proc killTheProgram {.noReturn.} =
  quit(0)

proc raiseSomething {.noReturn.} =
  raise newException(ValueError, "Something")
```